# Adjusting the width of facet plots, facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

Can I increase the overall width of the facet plots so that all the labels can fit? Or is there any way to prevent the labels from overlapping with another?

```
mydata2 <- temperature %>% filter(month == 1 )

mydata2 %>% ggplot(aes(x = year , y = mean_max , color = station_name)) +
  geom_jitter() + 
  facet_wrap(~station_name)
```

[[image: My plot1]

Comment: You can rotate the labels with `+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))`

Comment: Sure, there are lots of ways--depends on how exactly you want to achieve that. Wrap the facet labels (`labeller_wrap`), shrink the text size for the labels in the theme, move the legend to the bottom, truncate strings in the labels...

Comment: But if this is your full plot, you might first take a step back to figure out what you actually need to display and how. Right now, your data is split by station name into facets, making the color scale visually redundant. But because you have those colors, you need a legend, which takes up half your chart space and causes the problem of overlapping labels in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

1. Rotate the x-axis labels with:

```
ggplot() +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))
```

2. Move the legend below the plot to create more space for the facets:

```
ggplot() +
theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

You can then also decide you want the legend in two columns with:

```
ggplot() +
guides(color = guide_legend(ncol = 2))
```

3. You can save the ggplot to a pdf/png with the correct sizes using `ggsave`